# Animated Videos

Tags: animation, photo-editing, video

The top knowledge I have in animations comes from Powerpoint presentations and I am looking to improve upon this. I really admire the way animated educational videos are made by several channels like Kurzgesagt, Science Clic etc. and want to be able to make something like that in the future. Any suggestions on how I can start and which resources should I use (software, books, etc.) ? I would love it even more if you come from personal experience. Thank you :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "shopping recommendations" are off-topic across most of stack exchange, as they are often either entirely personal or short-lived as a result of changing markets

Comment: Also note that video editing is generally off topic here.   Maybe Video Production Stack Exchange would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I have good news and bad news. Good news is that your at a path of learning. Bad news is that you are likely to fail because you most likely do not appreciate the amount of work that goes into animating stuff. So the first thing to ask is do you know how to draw a single frame of the thing you want to emulate. If yes then you can move into simple animation territory. Start simple something like Kruzgesagt is about 2-3 months of work even for a professional (it gets faster once rigging is done) but obviously a few persons can speed ot up a bit.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks for the advice, I'll be sure to ask related questions there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are vector animations made in Adobe Flash but Adobe Flash is now Adobe Animate. As far as I know it is the same workflow. On top of animation it supports Action Script 3, which allows you to control stuff by programming. For example I made a project that generated money at random locations and scaling them down, which creates the illusion of money falling on a table. However knowing Action Script is not necessary to animate stuff. It's very easy actually.
Creating animations like Kurzgesagt is easy but takes a lot of time because in simple words his videos are hundreds of animated illustrations. At some point in time browsers had Flash plugins which allowed for mind blowing websites with gradients, custom fonts, sound, video and animation. It was very cool. :)

Comment: According to the authors they use illustrator and after effects

Comment: @joojaa Could be but I think Adobe Animate is easier. I think Kurzgesagt is all vectors in Animate and now I saw Science Clic and they definitely (also) use After Effects. For some reason I felt the question is about how to create the animated vectors style.

Comment: Thats fine but you can not start your post with "Those are vector animations made in Adobe Flash" if you know do not know that to be factually true. The big benefit of using after effects is that a) it has better text animations B) better motion blur c) better animation curves d) 3D so you can just orbit a object around another and it goes back behind the other at appropriate times, While i agree this workflow has a learning curve. This si almost never really the thing that rocks the boat because the time investment to one series is still in the magnitude of man months

Comment: @joojaa Keep it fun bro. I answer questions for fun and of course it becomes something on the internet and there is a lot of wrong information on the internet but let's not cry about it. My answer is useful, because there were none. If you posted your answer before me and explain all of this, I would have upvoted your answer and not bother guessing but you didn't. "You can't start" ... well, let's see ... I did, so I can.

Comment: Well had you said that could be done with flash i might have upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kurzgesagt has said in a video that it more than a month on some videos with a team of people, not only for animation, but also script and content. So it needs some work.
2. PowerPoint has many interesting options for animation. I have not seen many ppl that really explore in-depth the capabilities of the animation tools it has.
3. But you need to define what is what you really need. 2D vector animations normally need 2 types of programs.

a. A vector drawing one. Illustrator, CorelDraw, Affinity Design, Inkscape.

b. An animation software. After effects, Adobe Animate, Hit Film. It also can be animated with 3D software like Blender. There are some other types of vector animation software like Cartoon animator, or Moho Animation.

You need to define if you want to animate characters, elements or overall situations.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned likely Animate CC is what you are looking for (vector based animation software). But adobe software tends to be expensive so to start with my approach would be to google "free Animate CC alternatives" and try out what works best for your project...
https://blog.appsumo.com/adobe-animate-alternative/